# Ping Website in C# with WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I am working on an app for Windows 8. I need to detect if the user is connected to the internet. I can't use IsNetworkAvailable because that only informs if there are access points available. However, it doesn't tell if there is an actual active connection to the internet. To determine that, I thought I would try to ping google when I wanted to check to see if the user was connected to the internet.

My question is, how do I make a blocking call in WinRT? Basically I want to say:

```
if (Utility.CanPingGoogle()) {
  // I know I'm connected to the internet, do stuff
}
```

However, all calls appear asynchronous. I want to create a blocking call so that I can just toss the functionality in a utility class and use it as needed. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Check out the async and await keywords http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can make blocking calls to async functions.

> Data data = Model.SomeAsyncFunction().GetResults();

or using the Result property.

> Data data = Model.SomeAsyncFunction().Result;

Depending on the function you're using.

See if that works,

--Nima